# Rails to_param for pretty URL's--Can't get URL to change

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been trying to change the way the url appears in my language learning app. Currently it looks like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/langs/1
```

And I would like it to look like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/langs/1-be
```

Where 'be' is the first vocab/word entry in my 'Lang' database under the 'english' attribute.

Here are the changes I've implemented to try and get the pretty url to work (following RailsCast episode 314 in the intro where he talks about using to_param):

lang model:

```
class Lang < ActiveRecord::Base

  def to_param
    "#{id} #{english}".parameterize
  end

end
```

static pages controller:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
    @test = current_user.bookmark
  end

end
```

'bookmark' is an attribute in my user model used to 'remember' which word the user left off on learning. It is an integer value.

relevant view code/link I would like to change:

```
<%= link_to "Continue Learning!", lang_path(@test), class: "btn btn-large btn-primary"%>
```

Here is a sample find in rails console:

```
2.1.1 :001 > Lang.find(1)
  Lang Load (10.3ms)  SELECT "langs".* FROM "langs" WHERE "langs"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 => #<Lang id: 1, english: "be", english_to_spanish: "ser", spanish: "una", spanish_to_english: "a", created_at: "2014-07-11 01:30:53", updated_at: "2014-07-11 01:30:53">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `lang_path(@test)` with `@test` set to an *integer value*, and still expect anything inside `Lang` to be invoked. You need to actually pass in a `Lang` object to `lang_path` for `to_param` to even be present.

You need the following:

```
def home
  @test = Lang.find(current_user.bookmark)
end
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks also for the explanation. I will accept your answer once SO lets me.